# no operator " *= " matches these operands error generated when testing operator overload *=

Tags: c++, c++17

I received the following error message when trying to output the results of the operator overload `*=`

```
no operator "*=" matches these operands   
operand types are: ifs::units::Feet *= ifs::units::Feet
```

This part of the cout statement generated the error

```cpp
(comp19 *= comp20)
```

I understand that this is not allowed, but I don’t know how to get the output generated with the `*=` operator. This test works for `+=` but not for `*=`, most likely because `rhs` is a `double` in this case, but I am not allowed to change this to be an `Ftr` type.

How can I get the result using the given definition ? Any suggestions?

Here are the files:

Ftr.h

```cpp
#ifndef __FTR_H
#define __FTR_H


#include <cstdint>

namespace fun::calc 
{

    class Ftr
    {
    
    public:

        Ftr() = delete;
        explicit Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept;
        ~Ftr() noexcept;
        Ftr(const Ftr &other) = default;
        Ftr(Ftr &&other) = default;

        double getNum() const noexcept;
        Ftr operator+(const Ftr &rhs) const;
        
        Ftr& operator+=(const Ftr &rhs);
        Ftr& operator*=(const double &rhs);
        
        
    private:
        
        double m_Num;
        
    };

}
#endif;
```

Ftr.cpp

```cpp
#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fun::calc 

{

// FUNCTION:    Destructor

    Ftr::~Ftr() {
    }

// FUNCTION:    Constructor

    Ftr::Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept {

    }

// FUNCTION:    getNum

    double Ftr::getNum() const noexcept {
        return m_Num;
    }

// FUNCTION:    Overloaded Addition 

    Ftr Ftr::operator+(const Ftr & rhs) const {
        return Ftr(m_Num + rhs.m_Num);
    }
    
// FUNCTION:    Overloaded Multiplication

    Ftr& Ftr::operator*=(const double & rhs) {
        m_Num *= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

}
```

MainProject.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace fun::calc;

int main()
//mainFtrTest
{
    std::cout << "Ftr Class Testing Started ! \n\n";

        Ftr c(4);
        std::cout << "Ftr = " << c.getNum() << "\n\n"; 
        
    //  Addition operator
        Ftr add1(8);
        Ftr add2(7);
        Ftr total = add1 + add2;
        std::cout << add1.getNum() << " + " << add2.getNum() << " = " << total.getNum() <<"\n\n";
        
    //  Multiplication operator 
        Ftr comp19(9);
        Ftr comp20(7);
        std::cout << comp19.getNum() << " *= " << comp20.getNum() << " = " << (comp19 *= comp20);
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `operator *=` that takes a `Ftr`?

Comment: in Ftr.h I have the following                                                                    Ftr& operator*=(const double &rhs);

Comment: That shows how to `*=` a Ftr with a double. But where did you define an `*=` operator for `*=` with another Ftr?

Comment: Physically speaking, 1 Feet * 1 Feet = 1 Square Feet. The result is not in unit Feet.

Comment: Ftr& Ftr::operator*=(const double & rhs) {
        m_Num *= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

Answer (score 3):

`Ftr& Ftr::operator*=(const double & rhs)` means the right hand side of the `*=` operator should be a `double`. However, in your main func, you are doing `comp19 *= comp20` where the right hand side is a `Ftr` object. You can do `comp19 *= comp20.getNum()` to make your right hand side a `double`, but I think what you really want is to declare:

```cpp
Ftr& operator*=(const Ftr& rhs);
```

and define:

```cpp
Ftr& Ftr::operator*=(const Ftr& rhs){
    m_Num *= rhs.m_Num;
    return *this;
}
```

This will make the `*=` work, but you have another issue at:

```cpp
<< (comp19 *= comp20);
```

The right hand side of the `<<` operator is an `Ftr` object. You need another overload:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const fun::calc::Ftr& rhs){
    os << rhs.getNum();
    return os;
}
```

This overload cannot go into the class definition, because the left hand side of the `<<` operator is a `std::ostream` object. You must make it a non-member function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Adding comp19 *=comp20.getNum() worked. However I am unable to use ostream as you suggested because my header file contains a friend definition for the << operator as :                               
friend DataStream& operator<<(DataStream &stream, const Ftr &rhs);                                                                                                 which is inside the class and I'm not allowed to modify this. Any suggestions how to handle overloading << using that scenario?

Comment: @Lunden what is `Datastream`? If you have issues overloading, then maybe you already have the right definition.

Comment: Datastream is another class